# order by multiple fields in generic repository

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have following method in my generic repository which can order by a field name. I need to know how can I get it to order by more than one field.

```
public IList<TEntity> FindByExpressionOrdered(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter,
                                                params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] orderBy)
{
    IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> query = SessionScope.Current.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).OrderBy(orderBy.First());
    if (orderBy.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < orderBy.Length; i++)
        {
            query = query.ThenBy(orderBy[i]);
        }
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Calling the above as follows causes "Unable to cast the type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types." exception.

```
IList<Product> prods = IoC.Resolve<IRepository<Product>>().FindByExpressionOrdered(p => p.IsActive && p.IsFavorite, p => p.Name, p => p.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` for ordering expressions, it should work fine.

Then just change your method to

```
public IList<TEntity> FindByExpression(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter,
                                                    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> subSelector,
                                                    params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] orders)
{
    var query = SessionScope.Current.Set<TEntity>().Include(subSelector).Where(filter).OrderBy(m => true);
    query = orders.Aggregate(query, (current, order) => current.ThenBy(order));

    return query.ToList();
}
```

But one day, you'll want to choose the order direction... And will have to find a more clever way !

without the "OrderBy(m => true") trick, and with your comment (and with the same problem, if orderBy params is an empty array, this will fail) , I would do

```
var query = SessionScope.Current.Set<TEntity>()
                        .Include(subSelector)
                        .Where(filter)
                        .OrderBy(orderBy.First());
foreach (var order in orderBy.Skip(1))
   query = query.OrderBy(order);
```

Comment: i get a casting error IList<Product> products = IoC.Resolve<IRepository<Product>>().FindByExpressionOrdered(p => p.IsActive && p.IsFavorite, p => p.Name, p => p.Id)

Comment: public IList<TEntity> FindByExpressionOrdered(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] orderBy)
{
    var query = SessionScope.Current.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).OrderBy(orderBy.First());
    if (orderBy.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < orderBy.Length; i++)
        {
            query = query.ThenBy(orderBy[i]);
        }
    }
    return query.ToList();
}

Comment: Yes, you can avoid the `OrderBy(m => true)` trick to get an `IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>` which is needed to use ThenBy. But with your solution, and usage of params, you're not certain that `orderBy.First()` is not null !

Comment: @joblot by the way, the code given in your comment is the "failing" one or a correction for having it working ?

Comment: i have updated the code in the original post. i understand orderBy.First() could be null, which can be checked, but that is not the cause of exception i am getting.